# Assign IP address using Router and Switch (DHCP)

Tags: switch, router, ethernet, dhcp, ip-address

I currently have a router and I was wondering if I could connect one of the LAN ports to a switch to connect more devices through Ethernet. I need each device to have a local IP address. I know that when I plug a device to my router it assigns a local IP address, what I don't know is whether the devices connected through the switch will receive a unique IP address as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: I removed the off-topic consumer-grade router model from your question. The model is irrelevant. What you are concerned with is the DHCP server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switches don't get involved in layer-3 (e.g. IP). A switch is a transparent layer-2 device, so hosts connected to a switch will have no problem getting to a DHCP server on the same LAN.

Comment: So effectively I could use that configuration. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your setup is correct to get IP addresses delegated through the switch from the router to your devices if it is a home setup, where your router is already set up to delegate addresses through DHCP. A setup something like the below:

Cloud/Internet > Router (w DHCP) > Switch > Devices (will get IPs)

For a simple breakdown of a corporate setup, it's just like the above but...

Cloud/Internet > Router > DHCP server > Switch > Devices (will get IPs)

Hopefully that answers some of your question.

Cheers!